# System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException Was Unhandled byUSER CODE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm Not Pro, So Criticism Apart. I'am Just trying to show a User's Details To View. Having classes As **Employee**.cs (Emp_ID,Name,Age, etc) & **EmployeeContext**.cs as to Retrieve Employee information from DB.
my Employee Model Class is: [Employee.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXsRo.png)

My EmployeeContext Class is: [EmployeeContext.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdA15.png)

My EmpController Class is: [EmpController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ8OM.png)

i'am Just trying to show Details Of Employee (thats stored in Db) in View. but it gets with some exception unhandled, mentioned in **Title** of my Query.

### your suggestions Will be wellcomed.

Comment: check your database connection string

Comment: Avoid posting code in image links, post your code in question body. As the error said, check connection string part in web.config and post it here.